# Net activity - What does this network activity mean

Tags: networking

```
tcp     53 domain   LISTEN  *   *   .       
tcp     631 ipp     LISTEN  *   *   .       

tcp6    53564   ESTABLISHED     ::1     631 ipp     ip6-localhost       
tcp6    631 ipp     ESTABLISHED     ::1     53564   ip6-localhost       
udp     47568       *   *   .       
udp     53 domain       *   *   .       
udp     68 bootpc       *   *   .       
udp     631 ipp         *   *   .       
udp     46007       *   *   .       
udp     5353 mdns       *   *   .       
udp6    60160       *   *   .       
udp6    44496       *   *   .       
udp6    5353 mdns       *   *   .
```

Can anyone explain what this is? I'm I remotely being hacked through localhost?

Comment: Thanks for formatting, is anyone going to answer my question though.

Comment: why you think you are being hacked?

Comment: wouldn't you think the same? Can you just answer the question?

Comment: Not sure why everyone's down voting the question, seems perfectly reasonable to ask what certain network activity means. I've proposed a few minor edits to eliminate the buzzword "being hacked", you just want to understand what you're seeing from netstat.

Comment: @DavidParks I think most of the downvotes are from the [first revision](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/472581/1).

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing your question to: "What does this network activity mean," we can say that you have a couple of typical ports open to some process on your local machine. Port 53 is DNS, and port 631 is a printer sharing protocal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Neither set off any alarm bells for me, and they're just connected locally, so that means a process on your system (remember that using the network stack is a perfectly valid way for processes to communicate amongst each other).

What you should be asking is, "What process has these connections open" in order to identify the root cause of the connections. Here's an article on how to identify the process with that connection open.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-display-open-ports-owner.html

Comment: David, I went to the link you provided.  sudo lsof -i brings up a list I have users under the name avahi , root, nobody, and then my username. Is this normal?

Comment: That first column in the output indicates the process name. For example, on my system I see a port firefox has open: firefox    2147 allusers  139u  IPv4 269292      0t0  TCP 10.0.2.15:58793->nuq05s01-in-f31.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain David. One last question, how would I go about looking for keyloggers/ kernel modifications made without my knowledge . Is there anything command / program that can be ran or would I need manually find them if they exist?